# how to use exchange server DL(set of email IDs) In SharePoint 2013 People picker field?

Tags: 2013, workflow, designer

I have one list in sharepoint 2013.Here I am not able to give exchange server DL(set of email ID's) in People picker(person or Group) column. It throws an error like

> "Sorry, you are not allowed to share this with external users."

So, Kindly help me out to resolve the above issue.

Thanks,